# Handling Keycloak error "Could not pocess response from SAML identity provider"

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, adfs

I am trying to setup ADFS (Windows Server 2012 R2) SSO using Keycloak (12.0.2). On ADFS side all looks fine, but when I run test (using IdP-initiated logon on ADFS and trying to proceed to Keycloak), I see "internal error" Web  page and the below in Keycloak logs:

```
ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-1) Uncaught server error: org.keycloak.broker.provider.IdentityBrokerException: Could not process response from SAML identity provider.
    at org.keycloak.broker.saml.SAMLEndpoint$Binding.handleLoginResponse(SAMLEndpoint.java:512)
    at org.keycloak.broker.saml.SAMLEndpoint$Binding.handleSamlResponse(SAMLEndpoint.java:559)
    at org.keycloak.broker.saml.SAMLEndpoint$Binding.execute(SAMLEndpoint.java:259)
    at org.keycloak.broker.saml.SAMLEndpoint.postBinding(SAMLEndpoint.java:174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [...]
```

Are there any typical hints on how to study that ("could not process" isn't awfully informative)?

Thanks.